# comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions warning while make install?

Tags: c++, boost

I am running my below code which checks whether `data_timestamp` is more than two weeks old or not. If it is more than two weeks old, then print `hello` otherwise prints `world`.

```
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000;

    const boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    boost::chrono::hours twoWeeks = boost::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    boost::int_least64_t millis = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "<< millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    } else {
        std::cout << "World";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And my above code is working fine but there is one warning on this if statement comparison -

```
if (data_timestamp < millis) {
```

And the warning I am seeing is -

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

How do I remove this warning? I would like to keep `data_timestamp` as `uint64_t` since in the actual code it is being used like that in other places as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `millis` to a `uint64_t`. The problem you're having is that `millis` is signed, so you can fix it by casting it to an unsigned type.

```
if (data_timestamp < (uint64_t)millis) {
    std::cout << "Hello";
} else {
    std::cout << "World";
}
```

Comment: I see, will this be a problem if `millis` is in negative? Or do you think `millis` can be in negative or not?

Comment: @user2809564 Looking at the code, `millis` cannot be negative. It is the number of milliseconds in `now - two_weeks`, which will always be positive.